# Color detecting with transparent background PNG image in Python

Tags: python, png, transparent

I'm trying to detect colors in PNG images, which has transparent background.
However, Python recognizes every images are black because of the transparent background.
I want to make a code that classifies the transparent color to 'transparent' or nothing.

These are the codes I've tried.

```
rgb_im = img.convert("RGB")
r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((1,1))

def closest_colour(requested_colour):
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
        gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
        bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
        min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

def get_colour_name(requested_colour):
    try:
        closest_name = actual_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
    except ValueError:
        closest_name = closest_colour(requested_colour)
        actual_name = None
    return actual_name, closest_name

requested_colour = (r, g, b)
actual_name, closest_name = get_colour_name(requested_colour)

print ("closest color name:", closest_name)
```

Comment: Transparent means the alpha channel (the A in RGBA) is 0, it has nothing to do with the colors. Please add a `print(r, g, b)` in the third line, what does it say? And show some image you are working with.

Comment: @Joe I added print statement, and it says 0 0 0
And the image I've used is this [link](http://bitly.kr/YPIixUb)

Comment: Ok, in that case it might just be that for any pixels with alpha = 0.0 (full transparency), the value is black because it does not matter. Can you check that?

Comment: @Joe Yes, I was using the pixel in the background area. So I just changed the pixel's location to the colored area. Thank you for your help!